# VBA SQL Returning Statement, Not Value

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access

I'm working with a listbox, and when you click on a row it will populate the fields on a sheet.  So if I click work ticket 18, it will grab the department, priority, assignee, etc. from a table and fill the work order.  When I click on the row, I get a msgbox pop up with the ticket number by just writing:

```
MsgBox Me.Work_Order_List.Value
```

Then when I try

```
ticNum = Me.Work_Order_List.Value
strSQL = "SELECT Description_Of_Problem FROM Work_Orders WHERE " & ticNum & " = Ticket_Number;"
Debug.Print strSQL
Me.Notes = strSQL
```

My notes box will print the SQL statement but never run.  What am I doing wrong here?  I will need to populate many fields so is there a faster way as well?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After having to make multiple edits, I found that DLookup was not as convenient with multiple fields and an unbound form.  So in the end I have decided:

```
Dim myR As Recordset

Set myR = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("Work_Orders", dbOpenDynaset)
myR.FindFirst ("[Ticket_Number] = " & Me.Work_Order_List.Value & "")

Me.Update_Status = myR![Current_Status]
Me.Downtime_Code = myR![Downtime_Code]
Me.Date_For_Completion = myR![Date_For_Completion]
Me.Notes = myR![Notes_From_Assignee]
Me.Description_Box = myR![Description_Of_Problem]
Set myR = Nothing
```

And I use myR.FindFirst to grab the row I'm looking for.  Since my ticket system is still in the testing phase I only have ~100 records, but I'm hoping it will be able to search quickly when it reaches 10000+ with .FindFirst.

Answer (score 1):

```
Me.Notes = DLookup("Description_Of_Problem", "Work_Orders", "Ticket_Number=" & ticNum)
```

That was exactly what I was looking for.  I was able to delete the rest of my code and use those for each field.  Thanks HansUp!

Comment: Do tell, why are you dlooking up a bunch of fields (slow, uneditable) rather than binding a query or table (fast, editable)? Even if you just wish to write several fields to several controls, you would be better working from a recordset. DlookUp is for one or two controls and generally from a different table.

Comment: I chose this because I am unfamiliar with binding a query.  I tried the code you provided and tried to make it work, but I could not.  I will have to do some research on recordsets because as of now I open and close a recordset at the beginning and end of each sub, and I thought it would take more time to open and close each time when a row is clicked than a DLookUp.  So to answer your question: because I am still learning VBA and DLookUp worked for what I was doing.

Answer (score 0):

You are not running the query. You should set the recordsource of your form to the sql if you want the data to fill into fields.

```
 Me.RecordSource = "SELECT Description_Of_Problem, Other, Etc FROM Work_Orders"
```

The above will only work if you have controls bound to fields, but it is the easiest way to populate a lot of controls.

The best way to start is to create a form based on Work_Orders using the form wizard. You can then avoid any coding at all by creating a combobox to select records on your form. The user can then select a ticket and jump to that record. There is a wizard for that, too.

---

```
Dim rs As DAO.Recordset

ticNum = Me.Work_Order_List.Value
strSQL = "SELECT Description_Of_Problem FROM Work_Orders WHERE Ticket_Number =" _
       & ticNum 
Debug.Print strSQL
Set rs = CurrentDB.OpenRecordset strSQL
Me.Notes = rs!Description_Of_Problem
```

---

**Binding a form**

Start the form wizard based on a table or query

[image: Form wizard]

Follow through the steps to end up with a form in design view

[image: the form in design view]

There are a number of ways to navigate through the records, you seem to like the listbox. Add a list box making sure that the wizard is selected.

[image: select listbox]

Choose to find records on the current form

[image: find record on form]

And select the items to appear in the listbox

[image: select listbox items]

Select an item to find it on the form.

[image: select item to find record]

This is what makes it a bound form, the record source, which can be a table name, a query name or an SQL statement. Note that the control to be filled in automatically are bound to field names, but the listbox to find records is marked 'unbound'.

[image: bound form]