# How to Call A Query Into A Form In Access? (ms-access)

Tags: forms, ms-access

I have a query that you enter a number, and you get a result (it calculates something).

Now, I have a form with two inputs. In one input you type a number. After you type the number, I want my query to be called with the input's value as an argument, and then generate the number from query's result to the second input.

Comment: Take a look at this post: http://www.mrexcel.com/forum/microsoft-access/159034-using-visual-basic-applications-get-field-value-table-into-variable.html#post777289

Comment: You would need to use that first input as a variable in a `SELECT` statement.

Comment: @TKEyi60 The problem is how do I call the query and put the output in the second input

Comment: You call the query with the `Select` statement.  Then add a submit button. Then when it `on_click` triggers you use `Me.Refresh` to refresh the page.  Make sure you put the refresh last though

Comment: Try looking at [this_link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14782289/vba-sql-returning-statement-not-value) for a Select statement

Comment: @TKEyi60 I don't think that I undestood it. Can you give me an example for my case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an example VBA:

```
Private Sub Refresh_Button_Click()

Dim strSQL as String
Dim inputbox1 as String
Dim myR As Recordset

'set the input1 as a string
inputbox1 = Me.input_box_1

'this select statement creates a SQL string
strSQL = "Select whatever from table_name where field = '" & inputbox1 & "'"

'this recordset pulls your SQL statement so you can get your fields
Set myR = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset(strSQL, dbOpenDynaset)

'this gives the value of your second input box
Me.input_box_2 = myR!field_you_want_to_appear

Me.Refresh

Set myR = Nothing

End Sub
```

Comment: It tells me "Run-time Error '3061', And when I click "debug" it marks this line: `Set myR = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset(strSQL, dbOpenDynaset)`

Comment: I fixed it. That was because of the `''`, but now I got more problem. It says: "Item not found in this collection", and it marks this line: `Me.input_box_2 = myR!field_you_want_to_appear`. of course that I changed it, but it's non-English, so it's looks here Gibberish.

Comment: I fiexed it too, the column was with a space, so I puted it into `[]`. Thanks, now it works !!!